# Styling of EMAIL in PHP

Tags: php

i am trying to style up my message being sent from the contact form and following is my code i tried to do 
$message = echo "< hr>"; but the code didn't worked kindly let me know how can i style up my following message like change the texts colour, font size (HTML STYLING)

```
$message="Name : $name \r\n\n";
$message.="PHONE : $phone \r\n\n";
$message.="Company : $company \r\n\n";
$message.="Comments/Questions : \r\n";
$message.="---------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n";
$message.= $_POST['message'];
```

Comment: `$message = echo '<hr>';` won't ever work. You probably meant `$message = '<hr>';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use HTML markup in your email, you need to include an additional header in the [`mail`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3144) function:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Or, even better, use a library like [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/PHPMailer-Lite%20v5.1/). That way, you just need to tell it this message is HTML and it will take care of the headers for you.

**Edit**: forgot to mention, different email clients have very varied CSS support. In general, you should keep the styling to a minimum, test everything in various mail clients, read the helpful [articles of people who have already tried](http://www.sitepoint.com/code-html-email-newsletters/)... and accept the fact that some mail clients are just a nightmare.

Comment: i dont want alot of styling just simple styling like font size,colors that's it can you please give me a coding example i would appreciate that

Comment: Check [this link](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3144) - it shows you a simple example of how to send an HTML email.

Comment: thanx DCODER for helping me out

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
$message = "<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<title>Something</title>
</head>
<body>";

$message .="
    Name : $name <br />
    PHONE : $phone $domain<br />
    Company : $company<br />
    Comments/Questions:<br />
    <hr /><br />

</body>
</html>";
```

Comment: i received this lolxx in my email <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<title>Something</title>
</head>
<body>
Name : faizan qadri <br />
PHONE : 923455248812 <br />
Company : asd<br />
Comments/Questions:<br />
<hr /><br />

</body>
</html>

Comment: your code worked when i added $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

Comment: I'm only give message style.. no mention headers.. your header is correct

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know all other things, 
Use this headers in email for html email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
then you can write html email

$htmlMessage="Your styled message";
mail($to,$subject,$htmlMessage,$headers);
But be careful, gmail don't show images due to security reasons. and so html codes may not run and sometimes gmail (others too) may send your email to spam if headers are not correct.

Comment: I add this in my header and add up $message. = "<hr>" but received email something like this 

Company : Radiations3 

Comments/Questions : 
<hr>asdasdasdasd and when i did $message. = echo "<hr>" then the core didn't worked kindly give me a hint coding example then i hope i'll make it work